# Checking I have LaTeX packages installed

Tags: packages, installing

I want to ensure I have the packages `pst-pdf`, `auto-pst-pdf` and `pdfcrop`.

I run `tlmgr --gui` and search for these and appear to install them.

However, if then do `kpsewhich pst-pdf` at the terminal it does not return the location etc. (only `psfrag` returns a location). Does this mean the packages are not installed? If not how do I install them and why is the GUI installation appearing to work but not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`kpsewhich` is searching for *files*, not *package names*, so you need to add the extension `.sty` behind it:

```
kpsewhich pst-pdf.sty
```

Then I get:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-pdf/pst-pdf.sty
```

while without `.sty` I don't get anything printed.