# Automatically download and install packages from CTAN to compile a specific document

Tags: packages, linux, ctan

While working with some of my co-workers it happens that we have different versions of TeXLive. Because of that, some of them cannot compile my documents due to package missing.

A question came to my mind: What if it is possible to detect all packages and versions that are used for a specific document; see if that package/version is installed in the system; and if not download it and install it in a specific folder?

For compilation I always use a Makefile made by myself and I add there a `sty` and `bst` files if they are required for that document. But I do this manually. Thus I have this variable:

`TEXVAR = TEXINPUTS=./sty//:${TEXINPUTS:-:} &&\
    BSTINPUTS=./bst//:${BSTINPUTS:-:} &&\
    export TEXINPUTS BSTINPUTS`

I know from this question [Checking I have LaTeX packages installed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49484/checking-i-have-latex-packages-installed) and [Generate list of all installed (La)TeX files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23840/generate-list-of-all-installed-latex-files) that is possible to determine the full list of installed packages.

Moreover, I know that with the conjunction of `\RequirePackage{snapshot}` and `bundledoc` it is possible to generate the list of all packages that were used for compilation and copy them to my `sty` folder.

This is included in main file before `\documentclass`:

```
% List the files used in compilation
% It generates a 'job.dep' file that can be post-processed by 'bundledoc'
% Required for package-gen.sh
\RequirePackage{snapshot}
```

And the bash script `package-gen.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# package-gen.sh -- Generates the list of packages required for compilation

# Dependency file
MAIN=job

# Styles folder
STYDIR=sty

# List of files to copy (sty, def, cls)
#LIST=`bundledoc --listdeps=only $MAIN.dep | egrep -iw 'sty|def|cls'`
LIST=`bundledoc --listdeps=only $MAIN.dep | egrep -iw 'texlive/2015'`

# Create styles folder if it doesn't exist
if [ ! -d "$STYDIR" ]; then
    mkdir $STYDIR
fi

# Copy files to temporary folder
for file in $LIST; do
    cp -rf $file $STYDIR
done
```

So the question is: does anyone know how can I do this automatically... downloading the packages from `CTAN` that are not installed in the system and copy them to `sty` folder? It would be desirable to do it on fly, i.e., right after compilation starts.

Comment: MikTeX does this.  But it's windows only.

Comment: Yes. But I am searching for something for Linux.

Comment: I'd be wary of downloading random *executable* content from the Internet...

Comment: Well, it is not random. It is specific packages from CTAN. Only the ones that are not locally installed.